# Commercial video games

Tags: programming-languages, xbox360, playstation3

What language are ps3 and xbox 360 game written in? Are the games written in the same language for both systems? Also is the code something you could run on a computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What language are ps3 and xbox 360
>   game written in?

They can be written in any language that compiles to machine code supported by those devices; most likely only C and C++.

The xbox requires the use of DirectX (Xbox stands for DirectX box), so you'll have to use that as your 3d framework.

> Are the games written in the same
>   language for both systems?

Yes, same language but usually different 3d framework (I don't think the PS3 supports DirectX)

> Also is the code something you could run on a computer?

Yes. Obviously you would have to compile it first for your computer's architecture, and change some parts of the code (mainly the way you get input, from a keyboard instead of a controller)

Comment: I would mention emulators too, to more thoroughly answer "Also is the code something you could run on a computer?" - this needs a sort of "yes and no" answer, to clarify that sure the source code could be ported but the machine code needs a layer of emulation.

Answer (score 3):

From your starting point, I'd look to try out Microsoft's XNA.

Microsoft is known for it's developer support and well thought out frameworks, and in the current video games environment, this is certainly the case.

To become a senior video games professional, you'll most certainly need to learn C/C++, but to start off with, XNA's managed environment and C# are both "easier", and yet considerably powerful.

check more info:

[XNA Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)

[XNA Dev centre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx)